# Force.Com IDE Unable to load org details

Tags: eclipse

After installing Eclipse Kepler, all required JRE, and the Force.Com IDE. I then create a new Force.Com project and provide valid login information to my org I get the following error after a few seconds:

> Unable to load org details

Looking at the Salesforce log, I don't see any logins. I am behind a corporate firewall, which Eclipse has correctly identified. My General -> Network Connections are using the "Native" setting that Eclipse found (the IP and Port is valid).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Proxy IP and Port are correct, but the login was wrong. To make Eclipse work behind my corporate firewall, I had to change the Active Provider to manual, and edit the proxy information for HTTP and HTTPS to include my corporate proxy IP, Port and login. Once saved, everything worked as expected.

Comment: This helped me, thank you. Key was putting in my corp/NT credentials in the manual settings. Sorry I can't upvote your answer as I've not built up the rep yet.